# asp.net - How does parallel.for works

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

How does parallel.for works. Does it invoke threads for each loop/ divide the loops in parts and execute them in parallel? If it does then can we ensure the same result as normal for loop? I tested for performance and it really uses multi core processors. But i want to know the internal working as to how this works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Parallel.For` partitions the work for a number of concurrent iterations. Per default it uses the default task scheduler to schedule the iterations, which essentially uses the current thread as well as a number of thread pool threads. There are overloads that will allow you to change this behavior.

A parallel loop may look very similar to a regular loop, but there are actually a number of important differences. First of all the order of the iterations is not guaranteed. I.e. the code cannot assume any specific order. Doing so will lead to unpredictable results.

Also, since the code may be run on multiple threads exception handling is completely different from a regular for loop. `Parallel.For` will catch exceptions for the threads and marshal these back to the calling thread as inner exceptions in an instance of `AggregateException`.

For additional details please check [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx) by Microsoft patterns and practices.

Answer (score 2):

parallel.for loops run iterations of the loop in different processes in parallel. You can only use this if iterations are independent of one another. Only if the iterations are independent, you can assume the same results will be produced by a parallel and non-parallel for loop.

Comment: Just to clarify, you also can't control the sequence in which the iterations will take place.

Comment: @Brian: I think we can control the sequence in which the iteration will take place by using Interlocked.Increment.

Comment: @user329755: That was my comment :) I'm not so sure the for structure will play well in to that, but I have never tried it. Seems to me it's like going around the entire for mechanism.

Comment: In that case what is the use of parallel?? Real time applications will have loops with complex logic and not the ones we use in examples. How can we use it then. For example, the use of PLINQ, if i use parallel in list.findFirst, Which object it will return?

Comment: Lets say you need to insert 1000 rows of data in to a table. The inserts are independant and the sequence of inserts is not important. You can use parallel for to do the inserts. (DB server table locking issues are outside the scope :))

Comment: That is what i am trying to say here. We have to evantually handle locking and that would be a complex task. And if we want to do that, why use parallel?? We can do that using Threading. Why use Parallel?

Comment: parallel.for is just for when you want to do something simple, where iterations are independant. It's Threading for begginers, if you like. You don't have much control and it's not equipt to handle locking and sequencing, etc. It's just not powerful enough for your application, it would seem.